# unable to fit image into sencha touch panel with same size

Tags: background, touch, extjs

I created a panel using sencha touch with 300 x 400 pixel.  I have an image with the same dimensions, created using photoshop.  I used the image as the panel's background using css:

```
#pnl {
  background: url(img/bg.png);
  no-repeat;
}
```

the problem is that the image is way too huge and only displays about half.  I've added `max-width: 100%` but the result is the same.

What have I done wrong?  is there a way to fit any image on any size to a panel?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JS:

```
App.somePanel= new Ext.Panel({
    cls: 'somePanel',
    html: '<h1>Welcome to my app!</h1>',
    //some other properties
});
```

CSS:

```
.somePanel {
       background-image: url(http://somesite.com/someimage.png);
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```